# Javascript, react hooks: access member property of member object using same function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a basic question to access the property of an object of the member.

state.group - OK
state.person(object) - Not OK

Here is a react sample code:

https://codesandbox.io/s/access-perperty-of-member-2hm4e?file=/src/App.js

I made updateState function which has setState. 
This function is reading the name and value pair and update state.
If the member is has value directly, that's fine to update.
But if the member is an object which has the properties, what will be the best code?
I want to keep 'updateState' function for the all cases.

1. Here is the main function to update state

   > function updateState(e) {
   >       let name = e.target.name;
   >       let value = e.target.value;
   >       setState({ ...state, [name]: value });   }
2. OK:

   > ```
   > <input
   >         type="textbox"
   >         name="group"
   >         value={state.group}
   >         onChange={updateState}
   >       />
   > ```
3. Not OK:

   > ```
   > <input
   >         type="textbox"
   >         name="person.name"
   >         value={state.person.name}
   >         onChange={updateState}
   >       />
   > ```

   - No.3 is creating another member naming 'person.name'. my expectation is to access state.person['name'] which is the same as state.person.name.

Answer (score 1):

It should be `state["person.name"]` as "person.name" is the key used to store the value. Javascript objects are associative arrays of key-value pairs.

```js
const state = {};
state["person.name"] = "some value";
console.log(state);
console.log(state["person.name"]);
```

Given handler:

```
function updateState(e) {
  const { name, value } = e.target;
  setState({ ...state, [name]: value });
}
```

Input value should be:

```
<input
  type="textbox"
  name="person.name"
  value={state["person.name"]}
  onChange={updateState}
/>
```

If you have a more complex state shape, i.e. object with properties of varying depth, then you need to design your handler to match each property that *can* be updated, create separate handlers for each type of update, split up your state into easier to manage chunks, use a action/reducer pattern, etc...

Here's an example of splitting state up into chunks of depth no more than 2 (i.e. 1 level of nesting):

```
export default function App() {
  const [group, setGroup] = useState('A1');
  const [person, setPerson] = useState({
    name: "xyz",
    age: 31
  });

  const updateState = stateObject => e => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;

    switch(stateObject) {
      case 'group':
        setGroup(value);
        return;
      case 'person':
        setPerson(person => ({ ...person, [name]: value }));
        return;
      default:
        // ignore
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(group, person);
  });

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <label>Group</label>
      <input
        type="textbox"
        name="group"
        value={group}
        onChange={updateState('group')}
      />
      <hr />
      <label>Name</label>
      <input
        type="textbox"
        name="name"
        value={person.name}
        onChange={updateState('person')}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit access nested perperty of member]

Here I've split up the state and created a curried handler to take as the first parameter the "area" of state it handles, and the second is the event object. The state area goes into a switch statement to handle that state in a specific manner.

Comment: this is not working with a multi-depth object case.

Comment: @SGSNETWORKS it's based upon the information provided in your question, and it's how objects work. Javascript objects are associative arrays of key-value pairs. If you have state of complex object shape then you need handler(s) to match. I'll update answer.

Answer (score 0):

useState is used to take just one portion of state, and since your state is a nested object, in this case would be better if you use `useReducer`, [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/access-perperty-of-member-cxrxs?file=/src/App.js:67-1125) you can see an fork of your codesanbox in that style, but the code is something like:

```js
function reducer(state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "group":
      return { ...state, group: action.payload };
    case "personName":
      return { ...state, person: { ...state.person, name: action.payload } };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export default function App() {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, {
    group: "A1",
    person: {
      name: "xyz",
      age: 31
    }
  });

  if (state) {
    console.log(state);
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <label>Group</label>
      <input
        type="textbox"
        name="group"
        value={state.group}
        onChange={e => dispatch({ type: "group", payload: e.target.value })}
      />
      <hr />
      <label>Name</label>
      <input
        type="textbox"
        name="person.name"
        value={state.person.name}
        onChange={e =>
          dispatch({ type: "personName", payload: e.target.value })
        }
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

If your form will grow more, you can use something like formik to manage it.

Comment: In my case, to expend onChange event will be an extra effort to simplify codes.

Answer (score 0):

I updated 'updateState' function like this.

```
let name = e.target.name;
let value = e.target.value;
let objnames = name.split(".");
let obj = state;
let objdepth = objnames.length;
if (objdepth > 0) {
  for (let idx = 0; idx < objdepth; idx++) {
    if (idx + 1 === objdepth) obj[objnames[idx]] = value;
    obj = obj[objnames[idx]];
  }
}
setState({ ...state });
```

This function solved a multi-depth member access issue.
Here is the sandbox for a complex state access case.

https://codesandbox.io/s/access-nested-perperty-of-member-2f3wp?file=/src/App.js:651-1048

if anyone has a better idea, please share it with us.

Thank you.